# How to install UNIX into my USB?

Tags: unix, operating-system, usb

I searched for a long time and I don't have answers. I know how to install Ubuntu or Linux, but I want to know how to install UNIX and where I get installing programs from.

Can you tell me where you find UNIX installer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to instal Ubuntu on a flash. It should work the same way for a unix distro.
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-mount-usb-disk-drive-in-unix-or-linux/

Comment: But where do I get the UNIX installer?

Comment: do you not have a system currently running UNIX?

Comment: No, not at all, I uninstalled them, it's been 2 years. I want to reinstall it but the site i downloaded is gone. I want a new website to download and install it.

Comment: Third result on Google: http://www.unixdownload.net/
Is this what you are looking for?